# Updating Electron issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm working on an Electron app with ReactJS + Bootstrap and Typescript, and as I tried to update my Electron version (11.5.0) to the current one ([15.2.0](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable)) I stumbled upon this error message in the developer tools' console:

[image: Node error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"]

Ignore the warning since it was there before I updated Electron to a more recent version, the problem is that the app is completely blank and unusable. I tried googling and searching here in SO for the message but most posts and answers were related to Angular and a "polyfills.ts" file.

I also tried updating to a lower version (12.2.2) but it broke as well.

```
├── @types/electron-devtools-installer@2.2.0
├── electron-builder@22.13.1
├── electron-devtools-installer@3.2.0
├── electron-fetch@1.7.4
├── electron-rebuild@3.2.3
├── electron@12.2.2
```

This is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "asdfasdf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "preload": "./dist/preload.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently --success first \"npm run dev:electron\" \"npm run dev:react\" -k",
    "dev:electron": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.electron.config.babel.js --mode development && electron .",
    "dev:react": "NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config webpack.react.config.babel.js --mode development",
    "build:electron": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.electron.config.babel.js --mode production",
    "build:react": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.react.config.babel.js --mode production",
    "build": "npm run build:electron && npm run build:react",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w serialport",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|yml|yaml|css|md|vue)\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "productName": "asdfasdf",
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    }
  },
  "browser": {
    "[module-name]": false
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/firmata": "^0.19.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.54.16",
    "@types/react-plotly.js": "^2.2.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.0",
    "dpdm": "^3.8.0",
    "electron": "^11.5.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.13.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.2.6",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@serialport/bindings": "^9.2.4",
    "@types/johnny-five": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^6.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.0",
    "electron-fetch": "^1.7.4",
    "firmata": "^2.3.0",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "johnny-five": "^2.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node-gyp": "^8.3.0",
    "nodebots-interchange": "^2.1.3",
    "plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "serialport": "^9.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run format"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.+(js|jsx)": "eslint --fix",
    "*.+(json|css|md)": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

I also have these two Webpack config files:

**webpack.electron.config.babel.js**

```
import { resolve as _resolve } from "path";

export const resolve = {
  extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
};
export const devtool = "source-map";
export const entry = {
  main: {
    import: "./electron/main.ts",
    dependOn: "preload",
  },
  preload: "./electron/preload.ts",
};
export const output = {
  path: _resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "[name].js",
};
export const target = "electron-main";
export const module = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    },
  ],
};
```

And **webpack.react.config.babel.js**:

```
import { resolve as _resolve } from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";

export const resolve = {
  extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  mainFields: ["main", "module", "browser"],
};
export const entry = "./src/App.tsx";
export const target = "electron-renderer";
export const devtool = "source-map";
export const module = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "images/[hash]-[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
export const devServer = {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  compress: true,
  hot: true,
  port: 4000,
  devMiddleware: {
    publicPath: "/",
  }
};
export const output = {
  path: _resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "js/[name].js",
};
export const plugins = [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()];
```

I'm using the latest LTS version of Node (16.13.0) if that's of any help.

The code that's breaking is from a file which I didn't manually generate so I doubt it's of any use but here's **jsonp chunk loading** (*global is undefined*):

```
global["webpackHotUpdatebiomech"] = (chunkId, moreModules, runtime) => {
    for(var moduleId in moreModules) {
        if(__webpack_require__.o(moreModules, moduleId)) {
            currentUpdate[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
            if(currentUpdatedModulesList) currentUpdatedModulesList.push(moduleId);
        }
    }
    if(runtime) currentUpdateRuntime.push(runtime);
    if(waitingUpdateResolves[chunkId]) {
        waitingUpdateResolves[chunkId]();
        waitingUpdateResolves[chunkId] = undefined;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please show the line of code that reported the error  @Lucas S. G.

Comment: @Maxpan the problem is that I can't get past that point since the origin that the error is referring to is from a file which I didn't create but one which is automatically generated during the bundle. I'll still add the code that's breaking in case it's of use.

Comment: I think the discussion here will be illuminating and there are several alternate solutions, one of which will probably work for your code: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10035

Comment: Thank you @Mordred, your link to that webpack issue partially helped me. There are only two solutions there, one involves adding a small script to my **index.html**, which didn't work. The other "solution" is to **set contextIsolation to false**, which opens your app up to **security issues** since the renderer process and Electron's internal logic are no longer isolated. In my case I don't think it'll be so problematic, but there should be a better solution.

Comment: This code in my project fixes the issue `<script>var global = global || window;</script>`. I have no idea what is requiring it

Answer (score 3):

Adding `<script>var global = global || window;</script>` to your index.html file will resolve the issue. I tried to remove it and am getting the same error you are.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use context isolation ( I agree with the Electron team's rationale for `contextIsolation: true`, IF you EVER plan to load 3rd party websites or even your own website that has 3rd party javascript running, as they could access your IPC calls ). However if you treat the app as a secure app and never load third party websites or scripts, then it's fine to turn off.

If you still want to go ahead, modify the `next.config.js`:

```
if (!isServer) {
  config.target = 'electron-renderer';
  config.node = {
    __dirname: true,
  };
}

config.output.globalObject = 'this';
```

Comment: This is  for Next,js + Electron